# Updating prices for product groups in django

Tags: django, django-models, architecture

This question concerns django project architecture.
I'm building small shop, where sellers can upload their digital products. The system is querying the database and updates products parameters. I want to have system which sets prices based on these parameters, and have possibility to update prices for different product groups based on these parameters, in django admin. Base price plus extra for every known parameter. Every product has several fields, every field could have different values. Extra prices are based on the values. So I suppose it should be some model, like `Prices`. I have a vision of how I can do this with dictionaries. Hardcode param:price items, loop through them and voila. Can you guys suggest how can I solve this with django models? Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be Django Update query will help you in you case. It works like this

```
ModelName.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4]).update(value='some_value')
```

Further documentation can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update)
For updating every record individualy, you will loop through all filtered values

```
records = ModelName.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4])
for rec in records:
    rec.field_name = field_value
    rec.save()
    # and so on
```

You can alse use `setattr` and `getattr` for updating values like this

```
for rec in records:
    setattr(rec, 'field_name', 'field_value')
    rec.save()
```

Comment: This will assign all updated objects the same price, not a price that is derived from other attributes.

Comment: I found that what I need is actually JSONField. Your update snippet solves some part of my, as it turned out, too complex problem. Thanks.